# Not able to get schema name for Linked Component in DXA2.0

Tags: dxa, web8.5, sdl-tridion, dxa-2.0, dxa-net

Below is DD4T code that I need to rewrite to DXA. Find the Schema name of the Linked Component and perform an action based on the schema.

```
    IComponent component = Model.Fields["linkedComponent"].LinkedComponentValues[0];
    if (component.Schema.Title == "SomeSchema")
    {
        if (component.Fields.ContainsKey("field1"))
        {
            string form = component.Fields["field1"].Value;
        }
        if (component.Fields.ContainsKey("field2"))
        {
            string formID = component.Fields["field2"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Fields["SecondLevelField"].Value;
        }
    }
    else if(component.Schema.Title == "SomeOtherSchema")
    {
        if (component.Fields.ContainsKey("someOtherField"))
        {
            string someOtherField = component.Fields["someOtherField"].Value;
        }
    }
```

Is this possible in DXA2.0

Comment: Why don’t you try it and share your findings with us

Answer (score 1):

The DXA way of doing such thing is using Strongly Typed View Models and Semantic Mapping.

Using a smart combination of these two, you might not need additional logic at all.

In case you still need Schema-specific custom logic, you can test the type of the View Model (which maps to a CM Schema).

The given code fragment is too small/isolated to give an proper example of Strongly Typed View Models.

You could define View Model Types `SomeSchema` and `SomeOtherSchema`, which have a common base class. The propery `LinkedComponents` can then be of that base class (in general, these names are not ideal, because referring to CM Concepts; you should be using more semantic names for your View Model Types and Properties). This makes the `LinkedComponent` property *polymorphic*: the property is of a given type, but the actual linked entities will always be subclasses of that type (and you can test which subclass if needed).

Alternatively, you could define a Strongly Typed View Model which can represent the information from both Schemas and maps to both Schemas.

Comment: Thanks Rick.. Am yet to try this. soon will post approach that worked for me..